Traverse through a JSON and add new fields in Scala
I have a JSON structure that looks like:
{
  "A": {
    "NestedArray": [
      {
        "AlreadyHere2": "x"
      },
      {
        "AlreadyHere2": "x"
      },
      {
        "AlreadyHere2": "x"
      }
    ]
  }
}

I need to add new Json fields with the same CONSTANT value to specific parts of the existing json document so it becomes:
{
  "A": {
    "A_1": "CONSTANT",
    "A_2": "CONSTANT",
    "NestedArray": [
      {
        "AlreadyHere2": "x",
        "arrayValue": "CONSTANT"
      },
      {
        "AlreadyHere2": "x",
        "arrayValue": "CONSTANT"
      },
      {
        "AlreadyHere2": "x",
        "arrayValue": "CONSTANT"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Note: in the case for arrays, add CONSTANT to each element.
I have a list of the specific json paths available to use as a "traversal guide" that could have more values added to in the future so my implementation can't be tailored to the existing json structure. i.e.:
val list = List("A.A_1", "A.A_2", "A.NestedArray.arrayValue")

I see that there's this for recursively modifying JSON: https://circe.github.io/circe/optics.html#recursively-modifying-json
but I am not sure how I can handle adding to specific new fields and in arrays. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

With case classes you can decode-transform-encode
case class OuterClass(A: ClassA)

case class ClassA(
                   NestedArray: Seq[ClassB]
                 )

case class ClassB(
                   AlreadyHere2: String
                 )

case class OuterClass1(A: ClassA1)
object OuterClass1 {
  def fromOuterClass(outer: OuterClass, A_1: String, A_2: String, arrayValue: String): OuterClass1 =
    OuterClass1(ClassA1.fromClassA(A_1, A_2, outer.A, arrayValue))
}

case class ClassA1(
                    A_1: String,
                    A_2: String,
                    NestedArray: Seq[ClassB1]
                  )
object ClassA1 {
  def fromClassA(A_1: String, A_2: String, a: ClassA, arrayValue: String): ClassA1 =
    ClassA1(A_1, A_2, a.NestedArray.map(ClassB1.fromClassB(_, arrayValue)))
}

case class ClassB1(
                   AlreadyHere2: String,
                   arrayValue: String,
                  )
object ClassB1 {
  def fromClassB(b: ClassB, arrayValue: String): ClassB1 = ClassB1(b.AlreadyHere2, arrayValue)
}

def transform(jsonStr: String): String = {
  val outer = decode[OuterClass](jsonStr).toOption.get
  val outer1 = OuterClass1.fromOuterClass(outer, "CONSTANT", "CONSTANT", "CONSTANT")
  outer1.asJson.spaces2
}

val str =
  """{
    |    "A": {
    |      "NestedArray": [
    |        {
    |          "AlreadyHere2": "x"
    |        },
    |        {
    |          "AlreadyHere2": "x"
    |        },
    |        {
    |          "AlreadyHere2": "x"
    |        }
    |      ]
    |    }
    |}""".stripMargin

transform(str)

//{
//  "A" : {
//    "A_1" : "CONSTANT",
//    "A_2" : "CONSTANT",
//    "NestedArray" : [
//      {
//        "AlreadyHere2" : "x",
//        "arrayValue" : "CONSTANT"
//      },
//      {
//        "AlreadyHere2" : "x",
//        "arrayValue" : "CONSTANT"
//      },
//      {
//        "AlreadyHere2" : "x",
//        "arrayValue" : "CONSTANT"
//      }
//    ]
//  }
//}

